# How to format Excel document to display HTML in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have an excel table with rows of texts that i have displayed in r shiny, however the text in not displaying nicely, and so i'd like to format the text with HTML to make it appear nicer.

**What is currently shown** 
vaccinations were given on time or not. It only considers whether

**What I want**
•   vaccinations were given on time or not.
•   *It only considers whether*

Comment: How are you currently displaying it in shiny? Does the table need to be editable?  If you just want a static table to display, the `gt` package is great.  If you want to search, sort, and filter, you can use `DT`.  If you need to edit the cells, you could use `excelR` or `rhandsontable`.  Also, `reactable` is nice to use too.

Comment: @MichaelDewar Its currently pully from a List in Excel but i'd like the list to be formated with HTML.

Comment: Since you didn't give any details in your question, I don't think you will get an answer any more detailed then my comment above.  Check out those packages and see which one(s) meet your needs.